# Building a magnetizer

Tags: circuit-analysis, electromagnetism

I'm building a simple magnetizer for the realization of a physics experiment, bought yesterday components for the construction of the same, I am following the scheme of [this site](http://www.mecatronicaatual.com.br/educacao/1322-construa-um-magnetizador):

[image]

The final assembly should look like this:

[image]

On the website had this indicative of these materials for the construction of the magnetizer:

- Diode 1N4002 or 1N4007
- Incandescent lamp 40w or 60w
- Fuse 1A
- The primary winding of a small transformer

The components that are bought:

- Diode IN4004
- Fuse 1A
- Incandescent lamp 40w and 60w
- transformer of 9V and 500mA

So I have some doubts regarding the material bought, I researched on the internet and saw that the diode IN4004 contains these features:

[image]

On the site that I am following, still contains the caution notice:

> The higher lamp power, the greater the intensity of the magnetic field
>   created, but also the greater the current flowing in the circuit. A
>   very strong current may jeopardize the integrity of the coil used. The
>   values ​​indicated in the circuit must not be exceeded.

I wonder if with purchased components, will have to change some feature of my circuit so I get the same flow of current in the coil

---

### Edit

The circuit goes directly plugged in to 110v or 220v as shown in the circuit design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Marcelo Bonifazio,

I don't think you will need to change some features of the circuit just because of 1N4004 diode. If you observe the schematic asks for 1n4002 or 1N4007 diode without changing the circuit. What do you deduce from it? Any value between these range should be good to go, unless you change anything other than this which is not likely. I noticed that you some how plan to use the 9 volt battery instead of the AC power. If that is the case then it will not work unless you convert the battery into AC or rapidly switch it on and off. The reason for this is because transformer only works on AC power supply. Also the circuit will be a little too powerful for the 9v battery to handle. I might be wrong since I made a few assumptions, you may not be planning to use the 9v battery.

Good Luck!

Comment: sorry for bad english, then the description of the components I think I caused a small confusion,
the transformer that has bought the rated voltage of 9V with maximum current of 500mA, will use only the primary winding of the transformer

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio I think it should work in that case.  Considering that you have only changed the diode it will work as a charm. Good Luck!

Comment: Well, for precaution just changing the diode 1N4004 the 1N4007 diode, the circuit worked perfectly, tks :)